# Express PayPal checkout, Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying set up paypal express checkout using SOAP 2.0 API in ASP.NET C# code. First I try to use sandbox, I created seller/buyer test accounts, imported web service and then I try to get token, in my C# code I have:

```
        // Create the request object
        SetExpressCheckoutRequestType pp_request = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();

        // Create the request details object
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.PaymentAction = paymentAction;
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.PaymentActionSpecified = true;

        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType();

        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.OrderTotal.currencyID = currencyCodeType;
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.OrderTotal.Value = paymentAmount;

        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.CancelURL = cancelURL;
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.ReturnURL = returnURL;

        SetExpressCheckoutResponseType response = (SetExpressCheckoutResponseType) caller.Call("SetExpressCheckout", pp_request);
```

but on the last line of that code it throws an error:

The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

That I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You could use this library instead: https://nuget.org/packages/Moolah

Comment: It doesn't resolve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code certainly seems correct but the PayPal API can be finicky when it comes to a few things.  One thing to look out for is that it will generate exceptions when the payment amount is not rounded to 2 decimal places - can you try ensuring this is the case?

Also ensure that your configuration values are correct.  Aside from that the code you have posted is exactly what I used to use for the SOAP API.

I stopped using the SOAP API a while ago in favour of the NVP API, which in my mind is a bit easier to deal with: https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview

I made available a library to do all the work for you: https://github.com/davidduffett/Moolah

The instructions here show exactly how to use PayPal Express Checkout: https://github.com/davidduffett/Moolah#paypal-express-checkout

Comment: Hi David,
I tried your library and it give me an exception " The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." 
Can you please guide me to fix the problem?

Comment: Dude, amazing work with the library!, but look for Sarim's comment. There is indeed a small modification that needs to be made. @SarimShekhani: See here! http://stackoverflow.com/a/34950820/1057052

Comment: Wait! Nailed it! Thanks a million. Remember the link from my previous comment? Well, we just need to add ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; before using "SetExpressCheckout". In my case, just to be safe, I uput it before var gateway = new PayPalExpressCheckout(configuration)