# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.System.Net.WebException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, nopcommerce

I am using PayPalStandard plugin of NopCommerce. When I placed the order & make payment with paypalstandard plugin after successful payment on paypal, it redirects to merchants site. At that time it gives error:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Also I am using Sandbox account of Paypal for testing.

It throws error from this line:

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()
```

Here is code below:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(GetPaypalUrl());
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

        string formContent = string.Format("cmd=_notify-synch&at={0}&tx={1}", _paypalStandardPaymentSettings.PdtToken, tx);
        req.ContentLength = formContent.Length;

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
            sw.Write(formContent);
```

Comment: I started to see this happening a day or so ago. Perhaps an issue with the certificate of https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/?

Comment: 9-10 months ago it doesn't throws any error with sandbox. Is it issue of sandbox?

Comment: Also this code works with paypal account successfully. It happens with sandbox account only. So it is issue of sandbox account?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue connecting to sandbox(nvp), everything was fine then yesterday the message "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." appeared.

I believe PayPal updated their endpoints on 19/20 January 2016 to use TSL 1.2 and HTTP 1.1.

To resolve this, for .NET 4.5 and above add the following line of code before calling WebRequest.Create().

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @nqynik. This resolved my issue.

Comment: This answer helps me too. One thing that you should add in your answer: `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` is only available in .NET 4.5 or above, so if the target framework is .NET 4.0 then you will need to change the target framework.

Comment: You are a savior. Hopefully Microsoft updates its PayPal tutorial!!1

Comment: If you are using .Net 4.0 then you wouldn't get option for SecurityProtocolType.Tls12, in that case you can use following code:

 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; // SecurityProtocolType.Tls12


As given at this link-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939523/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-sandbox-account

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked for us was listed on the PayPal blog post, [Upcoming Security Changes Notice](https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/).  There are a number of things listed in the post, but the one thing which we did, and that worked, was **PayPal SDK Updates**.  We updated using NuGet and everything started working again.